# Is a market worth building in an science city?

Tags: civilization-revolution

Is there any point to building a market or a bank in a city that is targeting science output?

Answer (score 2):

No, cities will either produce science or gold, but not both.  Therefore, if you're target science output in a city, producing markets and banks would be a waste of time.

Comment: At least in the iOS version, this is not true. I'm looking at a city producing both right now.

Comment: @mattdm, I'm not aware of the iOS version.  My answer was based around experiences with the DS and Xbox 360 versions.

Comment: Actually, notably late in the game, it is possible for a city to produce both gold and science -- but one of them will typically be very tiny, as the boosts come from hitting milestones or being first to certain techs. (Eg, +5 gold in every city, this will make a science pump still put out 5 gold/turn.)